# What happens if I destroy all the tanks?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

In the main storyline, I've reached the point where

> there're a bunch of tanks outside GCPD.

I've tried a couple times (but had to give up because of how long it takes) to use the disruptor to sabotage and destroy all the tanks.

If I do have the patience to do so, does destroying them change anything (aside from a little bit of extra XP)?

Comment: You inadvertently punch a giant hole in the GC economy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally had the patience to do this. Got a few hundred XP, but nothing else happened. On the way out after, there were 60 tanks waiting. This seemed like a lot, but according to [this guide](http://guides.gamepressure.com/batmanarkhamknight/guide.asp?ID=31189), that's normal.

The only reason to waste time doing this is if you need another upgrade point and *really* need a couple hundred XP (I think the total was around 300-400).